# What does "off ..." mean in a script?

Tags: single-word-requests

Could anybody, please, enlighten me as to what "off" means in the following excerpts taken from the script for the TV show "Breaking Bad"? (I've also come across the same use of "off" in other scripts).

"Our two scary Cousins glare at Heisenberg. **Off them**,
wrathful and unblinking, their lips moving in silent
prayer... and us thinking ”Oh shit. THIS can’t be good...”

He stands chest-high, frantically splashing water at the last
few lumps of cash still BURNING poolside. **Off our hero**...

PAMELA
Alright. I usually open with “So
sorry you’re here...”
(**off Sky’s sad smile**)
Where would you like to begin?

PAMELA
And it’s not an apartment, it’s a
house that you live in?
(**off Skyler’s nod**)
Do you own outright, or is there a
mortgage, or do you

SKYLER
Okay. I will think about that.
**Off the two of them shaking hand**s -- friendly, but strained

**Off Walt**, staring at him... then lowering his head in assent:

**Off her**, frustrated and grieving and not allowed by
circumstance to even explain herself to her son...

The two slices are carefully mated. **Off come the crusts**,
sliced with a sharp knife.

**Off come their Canali suits**.

**Off these strange events**...

MARIE
He must have! Why not just say
it?! --
**Off Marie, left stewing now**

**Off Jesse**, maybe just now beginning to see the light...

Comment: Google is your friend http://ask.metafilter.com/97315/On-the-meaning-of-off-on-the-page

Comment: There is Writers Stack Exchange site at http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions where you may get an answer from an expert. They are not movie script terms so might be directions (from a directors script)

Comment: I count at least three different kinds of *off* here. Which one are you after?

Comment: all of them @RegDwigнt

Comment: Then this is too broad. Also, if you have watched the show, the meaning of all of them will be clear. And if you haven't watched the show — wait a minute, what do you think you're doing reading the script before having watched the show?

Comment: in a nutshell.. i've watched the movie; my hubby has also watched it.. he is trying his hand at scriptwriting.. he's russian.. he is reading all these scripts in english.. i can't help him with this "off" thing because i have never come across such like usage in my whole life..

Comment: in the movie everything was clear.. i nead to know the exact word for word translation.. or at least the meaning of these "off".. any help is much appreciated..@RegDwigнt

Comment: and by the way my husband mentions that the situation in which the script coincides with the film is nearly not-existent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Context - breaking bad](http://leethomson.myzen.co.uk/Breaking_Bad/Breaking_Bad_3x01_-_No_Mas.pdf)

All the "Off" mentioned are guidance to the cameras except these

> Off come the crusts, sliced with a sharp knife.
>
> Off come their Canali suits.

which means "they remove the crust" and "they remove their suits"

The rest are directions

> O.S. or O.C.- OFF SCREEN or OFF CAMERA. A character talks, or something happens out of view of the camera.
>
> [**Off**](http://www.screenwriting.info/glossary.php#off)
>
> Short for offstage. Typically written as (off) next to a character name when a character speaking dialogue is offstage while she speaks.

In [this link](http://ask.metafilter.com/97315/On-the-meaning-of-off-on-the-page) they also mention

> You can end a scene in a screenplay or teleplay with a line of action being "Off Fran's reaction" or some such, which means the scene ends on Fran's face, as opposed to a wide shot or a shot of something/someone else. That format's not limited to shooting scripts by any means.